# In Swift 3 and XCODE 8.2, Sound plays only when breakpoint is hit. How to resolve

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio

In the iBook named "app Development with Swift", there is a chapter to create an app of "animal Sounds"

The iBook is accompanied with a [downloadable source](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/swift/downloads/app-dev-curriculum.zip)

Refer to Lesson 18 in the iBook and 18_adaptiveUserInterfaces folder in the zip file.

Step 1. create the app as given in the iBook Lesson "Animal sounds" section.

Step 2. Run the project

Step 3. Click on animal button. No sound

Step 4. Now add a breakpoint in SimpleSound.swift file, play() function.

Step 5. Again click on an aminal button, and breakpoint is hit.

Step 6. Step Over few times and sound is heard.

How can this sound be heard without that breakpoint?

Comment: try to add delay to ur play()

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding a delay as given below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5), execute: {AudioServicesPlaySystemsound(soundId)})
    AudioServicesPlaySystemsound(soundId)
}
```